Storing the user detaills into model without knowing password. How to achieve this ? Using Omniauth
I am using omniauth, devise and rails with react.

Can I create the session using the omniauth user details ?
Will the provider provide the password, whether it may be encrypted ?
How to create user object, because the model has validation for password. But the omniauth provider does not provide the password, then how to achieve this ?

I have tried using the omniauth for login purpose, but i have never tried it for the registration purpose.
I am expecting to make available for registration as well.
